# merge maps inside objects java 8

Tags: java, maps

I have a list of objects `UserRole`, object `UserRole` has a map of attributes:

```
public class UserRole {
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    ...
}
```

I'd like to merge the List of the objects `UserRole` in the object `UserRole` (merge maps of attributes).

for example a user can have two or more different roles,  I need a mechanism that merges the permissions (gains highest visibility):

```
{
      "attributes": {
        "reports": "hidden",
        "overview": "accessible"},
        "attributes": {
        "reports": "accessible",
        "overview": "accessible"}
}
```

should be merged in

```
{
      "attributes": {
        "reports": "accessible",
        "overview": "accessible"}
}
```

How can I do this with streams?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried and the problem you are facing?

Comment: Please show what the Object is.  Is it another map?.  If so, what are the Types of the map?  They appear to be Strings.  Does the outer map have other keys besides "attributes"?